# How to remove all bandwidth limits for Tor relay?

Tags: relays, bandwidth

How to remove all bandwidth limits for Tor relay?
Is there some kind of an torrc option to do that?

***P.S.*** What I'm trying to do is to give tor relay as much traffic
 and resource power as I could. Also sorry for my bad English, I'm Russian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file `torrc` has an option `AccountingMax`. It is used to set the maximum number of bytes a relay can send and receive:

> AccountingMax N
>     bytes|KBytes|MBytes|GBytes|KBits|MBits|GBits|TBytes
>      Limits the max number of bytes sent and received within a set time period using a given calculation rule (see: AccountingStart, AccountingRule). Useful if you need to stay under a specific bandwidth. By default, the number used for calculation is the max of either the bytes sent or received. For example, with AccountingMax set to 1 GByte, a server could send 900 MBytes and receive 800 MBytes and continue running. It will only hibernate once one of the two reaches 1 GByte. This can be changed to use the sum of the both bytes received and sent by setting the AccountingRule option to "sum" (total bandwidth in/out). When the number of bytes remaining gets low, Tor will stop accepting new connections and circuits. When the number of bytes is exhausted, Tor will hibernate until some time in the next accounting period. To prevent all servers from waking at the same time, Tor will also wait until a random point in each period before waking up. If you have bandwidth cost issues, enabling hibernation is preferable to setting a low bandwidth, since it provides users with a collection of fast servers that are up some of the time, which is more useful than a set of slow servers that are always "available".

So if you remove or comment out `AccountingMax` in your `torrc` and restart Tor, it should use all the bandwidth it can.